# Many but one, alone but together

Tags: biology, evolution, brain, science-in-society

Could a creature evolve to have multiple consciousness ?

Let me add more details :

-They all live in the same body

-They communicate with each other silently

-They cycle  phases of work when one conscious control the body and others rest

-During the rest phase the other consciousness have other active roles

-They have human intelligence

-They can all sleep and dream

-They share memories

-They live every moment together but as different beings(like two persons watching the same movie)

Comment: Schizophrenia...

Comment: Sure could. Sure has. Ever seen Fight Club? Go watch it in either case. Furthermore: Please detail how what you're asking about is different from [what we see in humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_with_an_Ermine

Comment: Schizophrenic and narcoleptic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually some theory on how consciousness works suggest that we as humans already have this. That we have several different streams of consciousness that work in cooperation with each other.

I read some texts on this some years ago. One of them described how when we try to solve a problem and get stuck, and then we go do something different for a while, and then suddenly we realise how to solve the problem seemingly out of the blue.

What is suggested to happen here is that one or more streams of consciousness recognise a problem as important when we struggle with it and it takes it upon itself to look for solution. Then when it finds a solution it presents it to the the rest and we feel like we've had an epiphany.

This makes sense to me because it makes the brain capable of working on complex problems while other parts are free to keep alert of the surroundings and ensure survival.

I'm not sure if the streams of consciousness that we experience as the self that is alert to its surroundings stay the same. But then again I tend to think about the sense of self as an illusion anyway.

Comment: Had to upvote...human consciousness is an illusion at best of a variety of processes mashed together and called one.  Best answer = we already are...the illusion is we think we are only one

Comment: @Twelfth is you see it that way you might like this video on a theory of how mind arise from matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvFE1Au3S8U
It's my favorite so far.

Comment: Thanks, so my creature only needs to  have human intelligence plus something that makes it aware of having more than one conscious ?